# multiple animations in raphael.js

Tags: raphael, transform

I have drawn a box. The first animation makes the box move horizontally and the second one moves the box vertically. But when the second animation is executed the box first comes back to its original position and then animates vertically. What I want is that the box shouldn't come back to its original position and where the first animation ends, the second animation must execute exactly from that position. How can I achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

JS Fiddle [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/CfH7G/)

```
window.onload = function (){
    var paper = Raphael(0,0,800,400);

    var hi = paper.rect(10,10,100,30);

    var move1 = Raphael.animation({
        transform:'t100,0'
    },1000);

    var move2 = Raphael.animation({
        transform:'t0,100'
    },1000);

    hi.animate(move1);    
    hi.animate(move2.delay(1000)); 
}​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey here's the updated working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfH7G/1/)

The reason being as you may know small `t` transforms relative to the current position of the rectangle. By current position it means the  `x and y`  attributes of the `element`, the rectangle in our case.

But the first line in [Element.transform](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) says

```
 translation doesn’t change x or y of the rectangle
```

Which means after you perform `'t100,0'` the  `x & y` attributes of the rectangle is still the initial `10,10` Hence the second animation is executed with respect to  `10, 10`

Finally, for the result you are expecting, you need to be able to change x & y attributes which can be done as shown in the fiddle....Hope this helps !

Comment: you might also consider using Element.translate instead, but Raphael doesn't encourage us to use it...

Comment: thanks for the explanation. now if I want to want to animate it more than twice. lets stay in the following order: right,down,left,up to its original position. how can i do that?

Comment: And if you are looking for animating along a path then, follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032541/how-to-animate-a-raphael-object-along-a-path

Comment: that's brilliant... was that specified in the Raphael reference? How did you know about it? I would like to expand my knowledge as well. Thanks :)

Comment: It's not specified in the reference, but go through the source code of Demos given on the raphael website when free, which will teach alot of stuff which is not documented...