# How to curl paths into spiral on hover using Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I have a set of Raphael paths that I want to animate when a separate path is hovered over.

The client sent an SVG illustration that I had converted into Raphael code.  This is just a small section of the larger image.

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

[starting canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd78D.png)

Start with a set of path objects in a line.  When you hover over the red path they animate in a spiral until they form

[ending canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EpVP.png)

I've done some research, and I think that I'm going to have to animate each circle along a hidden path that depicts the arcs they have to move to get to the final spiral shape ([Animate along a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032541/how-to-animate-a-raphael-object-along-a-path)), but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to create this animation.

On top of that, I'm not really sure how to calculate the angle and size of the hidden paths the circles would be following.  What is going to be the best way to create this animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think moving each circle along a hidden path is easiest way.

I would suggest to create a new SVG file in InkScape vector editor, draw circles in start and end positions and then connect them with arcs. Save the file. Then open the file in any text editor and copy all data  to your JS code (copy path's "d" parameter and coordinates of circles).

Answer (score 0):

It's been more than one year since it's asked but maybe it might help other people.

Using simple algebra thought in high school you can define two functions: linear and spiral.

```
function linear(i){
    x = i*15;
    y = x;
    return {cx:x+offset,cy:y+offset};
}

function spiral(i){
    r = 50 - i*5;
    x = r*Math.cos(i);
    y = r*Math.sin(i);
    return {cx:x+offset,cy:y+offset};
}
```

This is just a 5 min fiddling, so it might seem cheap. Of course, you can define better algorithms using `transform` functions.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/meanyack/Qt6yF/)