# javascript how to move element on route on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, move, parallax

I have a route like a vertical snake.  (like this http://www.my-favorite-coloring.net/Images/Large/Animals-Reptiles-Snake-31371.png )

How I can move element (circle 10x10) on route by X and Y position on scroll?

Horizonal is ok :

```
    var coin = $('#coin');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var coinTop = coin.css('top'),
            cointLeft = coin.css('left');

        if($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && $(window).scrollTop() < 600){
            $("#coin").css({ "left":  contLeft + 'px' });
        };
    });
```

But how I cat move it smoothly along the route?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using a vector (SVG) library, namely **raphael.js** for the animation part.

In raphael.js you can define a path and then animate any object along the length of that path.

Please see the example and a corresponding stackoverflow thread for better understanding:

- http://raphaeljs.com/gear.html
- [How to animate a Raphael object along a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032541/how-to-animate-a-raphael-object-along-a-path)

Compared to the thread, you need to attach the animation on the onScroll event, as opposed to attaching it to a Interval.

**Edit:**

Adding the relevant code snippet from the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPX78/), as the commenter suggested:

HTML:

```
<div id="holder"></div>
```

JS:

```
var e;
var myPath;
var animation;  //make the variables global, so you can access them in the animation function
window.onload = function() {
    var r = Raphael("holder", 620, 420),
        discattr = {
            fill: "#666",
            stroke: "none"
        };
    function curve(x, y, zx, zy, colour) {
        var ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + x;
        var ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + (y - 100);
        var bx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + (zx - 200);
        var by = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + (zy - 100);
        e = r.image("http://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/10310/Odysseus_boy.png", x, y, 10, 10);
        var path = [["M", x, y], ["C", ax, ay, bx, by, zx, zy]];
            myPath = r.path(path).attr({
                stroke: colour,
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "stroke-linecap": "round",
                "stroke-opacity": 0.2
            });
        controls = r.set(
            r.circle(x, y, 5).attr(discattr), r.circle(zx, zy, 5).attr(discattr));
    }
    curve(100,100,200,300,"red");
    animation = window.setInterval("animate()", 10);  //execute the animation function all 10ms (change the value for another speed)
};
var counter = 0;    // a counter that counts animation steps
function animate(){
    if(myPath.getTotalLength() <= counter){   //break as soon as the total length is reached
        clearInterval(animation);
        return;
    }
    var pos = myPath.getPointAtLength(counter);   //get the position (see Raphael docs)
    e.attr({x: pos.x, y: pos.y});  //set the circle position
    counter++; // count the step counter one up
};
```

**Update:**

I've recently used [pathAnimator](https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator) for the same task. Be careful about the performance though, a complicated animation might be quite intensive.

Comment: Please consider posting the relevant content from the links here. If the links become unavailable in the future, the answer will become irrelevant.

Comment: Nice answer, couple suggestions. One way to make this "smooth" (as @Isis asks) is to ease the movement toward the final position.
1: Use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of an interval for maximum smoothness. 
2: Calculate easing like this: `x += (pos.x - x) * 0.2` (change the 0.2 to meet your easing needs)