# Multiple animations in Raphael (move line and circle plus transform the circle)

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I have a circle and a path (four small lines). I made a group of the circle and path (with lines). Now I try to move the group AND (while moving) transform the circle (s3).
Anyone any idea why this is not working?

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);

var circle = paper.circle(8, 8, 1).attr({ stroke: '#fff', fill: '#f00'});

var anim1 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "s3"}, 500);
circle.animate(anim1.repeat(Infinity));

var line = paper.path('M 0,8 l 5,0 M 8,0 l 0,5 M 11,8 l 5,0 M 8,11 l 0,5 z'); line.attr('stroke', 'red');

var group = paper.set(); group.push(circle, line);

var anim3 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "T 100, 100 R 360"}, 1500);
group.animateWith(circle, anim1, anim3.repeat(Infinity));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76CGE/

How can I move the path (with lines) and circle and while they move transoform the circle in the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there seems no possibility to run multiple animations at once in raphael, you are probably forced to cut your animation into pieces. this is not an elegant solution, but the result might be what you want to achieve.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/75ZFU/

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
var circle = paper.circle(8, 8, 1).attr({ stroke: '#fff', fill: '#f00' });

var anim1 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "s3 T 33,33"}, 500, "linear", function() {         circle.transform("s1 T 33,33").animate(anim2)});
var anim2 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "s3 T 66,66"}, 500, "linear", function() {     circle.transform("s1 T 66,66").animate(anim3)});  
var anim3 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "s3 T 100,100"}, 500, "linear", function() { circle.transform("s1 T 0,0").animate(anim1)});
circle.animate(anim1);

var line = paper.path('M 0,8 l 5,0 M 8,0 l 0,5 M 11,8 l 5,0 M 8,11 l 0,5 z');
line.attr('stroke', 'red');

var anim4 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "T 33, 33 R 120"}, 500, "linear", function() { line.transform("T 33, 33 R 120").animateWith(circle, anim2, anim5)});
var anim5 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "T 66, 66 R 240"}, 500, "linear", function() { line.transform("T 66, 66 R 240").animateWith(circle, anim3, anim6)});
var anim6 = Raphael.animation({ transform: "T 100, 100 R 360"}, 500, "linear", function() { line.transform("T 0, 0 R 0").animateWith(circle, anim1, anim4)});
line.animateWith(circle, anim1, anim4);
```

Comment: Thanks!
Bumber that it can not multiple. Problem is that this was just some little test scenario. The real solution has a path that is not easy to break apart in advance.

Comment: maybe [this stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032541/how-to-animate-a-raphael-object-along-a-path) might help. the animation along a path is done independently, with setInterval, and the translated object itself could be animated with .animate. maybe. otherwise, the scale would need to be done in setINterval as well. in fact, that would be the more elegant solution :-)